# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' python3 + proxy

Tags: python-3.x, text, proxy, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There are some question like this online but I looked at them and none of them have helped me I am currently working on a script that pulls an item name from http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories

I want it to pull this information from supreme uk but im having trouble with the proxy stuff but right now im strugglinh with this script everytime I run it I get the error listed above in the title.

Here is my Script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')

proxy_script = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    name = soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    print(name)
```

I am always getting this error and when I run the script without the .text at the end of the `itemprop=name` I just get a bunch of None's
like this:

```
None
None
None etc......
```

The exact amount of Nones as there are Items available to print

Comment: I got rid of the commented-out bits which weren't relevant to your question.  Try to keep your examples minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, I've commented the code that I've used below.
and the reason we use `class_='something` is because the word `class` is reserved for classes in Python.

URL = ('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')

```
#UK_Proxy1 = '178.62.13.163:8080'

#proxies = {
# 'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1,

   #'https': 'https://' + UK_Proxy1

#}



#proxy_script = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies).text

proxy_script = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')

thetable = soup.find('div', class_='turbolink_scroller')

items = thetable.find_all('div', class_='inner-article')

for item in items:
  only_text = item.h1.a.text
  # by doing .<tag> we extract information just from that tag
  # example bsobject = <html><body><b>ey</b></body</html> 
  # if we print bsobject.body.b it will return `<b>ey</b>`
  color = item.p.a.text

  print(only_text, color)
```